# Extract best values from string column in pandas dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to retrieve the first and last name of the person who has the highest percentage within a string column.

***Example of my dataset:***

| id | name_percentage |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Albert Beil (20%) John Cole (10%) John Ash Cruff (70%) |
| 2 | Thomas James (100%) |
| 3 | *null* |

***My desidered output:***

| id | best_name | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Ash Cruff | 70% |
| 2 | Thomas James | 100% |
| 3 | *null* | *null* |

I tried to reason with the split function but I can't find a logic to do it massively.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html), [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) & [`GroupBy.last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.last.html) :

```
extracts = df.pop("name_percentage").str.extractall(
    r"(?P<best_name>[^()]+?)\s*\((?P<percentage>.+?)\)").droplevel(1)

out = (df.join(extracts).sort_values(
    "percentage", key=lambda s: pd.to_numeric(s.str[:-1]))
           .groupby("id", as_index=False).last())
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   id        best_name percentage
0   1   John Ash Cruff        70%
1   2     Thomas James       100%
2   3             None       None

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Excellent as usual!

Comment: Doing my best, thanks Corralien ;)